# Comment not appearing on invoice email

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice, email-templates

I have created a custom template for the invoice email and added the variable `{{var comment}}` to the email template. The other modifications I have made to the email template does show, but not the comment.

I have added a few comments to the invoice, but none show up. I am referring to the email that sends when you have an invoice open and you click the Send Email button.

Comment: please show your php code which you have tried.

Comment: There isn't any php code, it's in the email template. I went to insert variable and it added `{{var comment}}` to it.

Comment: please show your email template html code, Also comment is stored in invoice table?

Answer (score 0):

When create new invoice, before submit, check to `**Email Copy of Invoice**` and **`Append Comments`** checkboxes.

[image]

Comment will come with invoice email like this.

[image]